# function not called with the same name as a class

Tags: c++

Why the function bellow `void i( )` is not called as in a 'Normal' function.

```
void i(){
    cout << 10 << endl;
}

int main(){
    class i { 
        int j;
    };

    i();// 

    return 0;
}
```

The normal behavior expected is to print 1O, but I did not getting anything, not a compiler warning nor the result.

Comment: The inner `i` is shadowing the outer one. You are calling the constructor of `class i` which does nothing in this case.

Comment: No, the 'normal behavior' is to call the constructor for the class `i`.

Comment: try to call it `::i();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The inner `i` is shadowing the outer one. You are calling the default constructor of class i which does nothing in this case.

The solution is to explicitly scope the call, as `::i();`

Comment: hmm, what's the scope for `class i`?  `main::`?

Comment: @ebyrob: It is local scope. There is no syntax to refer to it because it is usually not needed, although some tools such as debuggers may show it this way (`main()::i`).

Comment: For some real fun, see what happens when `class i` is out in global scope next to `void i()`.  Visual Studio 2010 actually allows this to happen, but the global class seems completely unusable.

Comment: @ebyrob It's allowed and legal. The global class is usable as `class i`.

Comment: awesome: `class ::i();` intellisense is going nuts with it though.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's trying to call "i" in the current scope:
You can call your function`::i()`;